# M2Doc - Provide new service error "can't load service class"

Tags: m2doc

I would like to extend M2Doc with a new service allowing me to resolve the model element identifiers contained in a constraint opaque expression (i.e. replace in the constraint LinkedText the html hyperlink with element ids by the element names). As far as I've understood a Java class with a default constructor and a method doing the magic would solve my problem.

I've created a separate Java project and selected in the template properties wizard of my template this service class but when generating the word document I get the error that the service class cannot be load ("<---can't load service class: org.obeonetwork.m2doc.services.ConstraintServices").

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You need the service project/plugin to be installed in your Eclipse. An other way is to use the version of M2Doc 3.0.0. It provide an integration with the JDT to load classes from the workspace. This can be used at development stage. Later you will need to deploy your plugin if you want to distribute your template.