# invalid type literal import - How to import and use my custom service

Tags: m2doc

So I created a simple service with a single class, without constructor : `services.RecursiveQuery` and added it as a plugin to my Eclipse instance as described in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59515891/m2doc-provide-new-service-error-cant-load-service-class).

According to the documentation the next step would be to import it in my template file file so I tried this:

```
{m:import:services.RecursiveQuery}
```

However I get this error in the validation file:

```
Expression "import:services.RecursiveQuery:services" is invalid: invalid type literal import:
```

What am I doing wrong ? It feels like I'm missing something. Also I was wondering how to use the `getAllChildren()` method of this service. I would have tried
     `{m:for child | services.RecursiveQuery.getAllChildren(self)}` but that doesnt feel right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The M2Doc documentation may be unclear on this point: `{m:import...}` is not a valid statement in a M2Doc template file. It should be used in MS Word document properties, not in the docx template file.

You should use the [template properties wizard](https://www.m2doc.org/ref-doc/nightly/#template-properties-wizard) to change imports along with the solution you mentionned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59515891/m2doc-provide-new-service-error-cant-load-service-class).

For a better understanding of how to use custom services you can check examples in M2Doc [sources](https://github.com/ObeoNetwork/M2Doc/tree/master/tests).

Comment: OK I finaly understood how to use my service. However I have to disagree on your answer. There is this exemple in the [documentation](https://www.m2doc.org/ref-doc/nightly/index.html#providing-new-services) `m:import:org.obeonetwork.m2doc.rcptt.a.ServiceClassA`

Comment: This is the syntax for the MS Word custom attribute storing the template properties. You can open your template in MS Word to see those [properties](https://www.howtogeek.com/217329/how-to-create-custom-properties-in-a-word-document/). To edit them you should use the [template properties wizard](https://www.m2doc.org/ref-doc/nightly/#template-properties-wizard). What I meant is that it's not an element of language.

Comment: Ah it's clearer that way. You can add this to your answer and I'll accept it.